# change return fetch directory

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am trying to understand why I can't change return fetch directory to my `/home` direcotory rather tahn `public_html` :

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/home/mysite/public_html/checkfetch.php, {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },
```

It works when I make like above but what I need is not `/home/mysite/public_html/checkfetch.php` but `/home/checkfetch.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this hosted? Whatever is accessible in a web browser on that host (not a local file path) is what can be used for fetch. Establish valid route paths on your server, and use those. Nothing else.

`public_html` is an abnormal thing to have included in a web path. Normally such a folder indicates the filesystem root of where web paths begin from.

Comment: No it is not accessible through brower. I am trying to make it safe to put fetch file in non accessible local path so anyone who uses simple tools to get the address can't execute the file which is used for fetch. I can't use `define()` due to some reasons. Therefore I was thinking that the only possible solution was this. I don't want the fetch url can be executed manually by users if they would have known this address.

Comment: You don't understand how fetch works, then. It is JS that is executed by the browser. It *MUST* point to an accessible *REMOTE* path, same as what you would put in anchor href.

Comment: Yeah, I confused..  I have tried too many things in order to prevent direct access to fetch address. I thought if fetch is called inside of our server then we might put any path there including local.

Comment: Fetch should call a public endpoint on your server. Inside that server endpoint (checkfetch.php in this example) is where, within your server environment (PHP in this case) you can then access local resources, such as files or a database. So this endpoint/route is the gatekeeper between the outside world and the inside of your server.

Comment: That is what I can't figure out, I have a line in the `checkfetch.php` : `require_once 'site-classes/Paypal-classes.php';  CreateOrder::orderCreate();` I am including classes and creating the order. So anybody who knows the link (`checkfecth.php`) can easily execute the url can execute the function? Is it right way to leave it like that? Isn't it should only be executed by PayPal or website itself? I was trying to find out What kind of flow can be developed here in order to prevent user to access that file directly? Because once it is executed, anybody can see json output.

Comment: Yes, anyone can access the endpoint, causing it to communicate with the PayPal API to create an order and return the response. That's what the endpoint is for.

Comment: Got it, Thank you for confirming and clarifying this.

Comment: Just for making sure wanted to ask is it possible to insert the data into database and send the exact data with `$_GET` variable to the fetch URL  and make checking in fetch address before proceeding. So if the button is pressed then we will look at database in fetch address and if data is in the database and has not been accessed before then we will allow to the user to proceed.

Comment: If by "Has not been accessed before" you mean "Has not result in a previously successfully captured payment before", then yes that can work. If you intend to block repeat create orders for the same address that have not resulted in a successful capture, that doesn't make sense. Such logic is more relevant to the capture route anyway

Comment: Yeah I meant the former idea you mentioned in your comment. I have left the users to access the `create` file which is resulted to create the order for authroize as much as they want, but once they want to authorize or capture then it checks the database and if we don't have that order_id then we block someone to access authorize / capture method. That make sense because only who presses the pay button can complete the process otherwise website gives an error.